# ORM & Logical Delete

Tags: orm

Do any of the available ORMs support using a bit field to represent row removal?

More information.  Working in C#.  I need to delete this way to support synchronization of remote database changes to a central database.  I'm looking for a possible ORM, but am also interested in approaches to the problem.  So if anyone knows any ORM in any language/environment that addresses this problem I would be interested in looking at it.  Thanks for the questions feel free to ask more if anything is unclear.

Comment: Your question is a little bit underspecified; care to tell us why you need it, so perhaps people could suggest similar features in ORMs or workarounds?

Comment: What language and environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not apply if you're not using .NET, but the LightSpeed ORM has a built in feature called "soft delete". Basically, when you have a DeletedOn field on your table LightSpeed will insert the time it was deleted. It automatically handles this on normal selects (e.g. where Deleted == null) so that the deleted items are not seen again. You could then write a sync process that detects the deleted state by checking that field.

You can of course instruct the querying engine to include deleted results.

[Mindscape LightSpeed ORM](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/LightSpeed/default.aspx)

I am making an assumption also that we're talking about the same thing here :-)

Comment: Exactly, It seems a common design. Not sure why it's not more wide spread.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to implement logical delete externally in your application, cause it's not very complex, but it will be more flexible. See [this article](http://alex-kofman.blogspot.com/2009/12/soft-delete-or-logical-delete.html) for details.